# Jmeter HTML Report Customization

Tags: jmeter

I have created HTML report by running the test from command line but the HTML report created is quiet confusing. So is there any  plugin which we can use to generate HTML report similar to VUgen report?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such report as the one you're looking for which is for Load Runner.

If you want to understand report, please carefully read:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

To create it correctly, follow this [tutorial](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/reporting-feature-in-jmeter/) by one of JMeter developers.

And then ask precise question on confusing report.

Comment: if you define your custom properties, then to the command add `-p youpropertiesfile`, in my experience even after I edited `user.properties` located in same `bin` as jmeter, it did not take them (though maybe partly due to me using alias to jmeter.sh).